# MatLab function that shifts points to the left or right from a max or minimum point

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out how to have a function that will find a point that is x number of points away from my set min and max in an array in matlab.

Lets say that I do `max(data(row 1:row 2,column))` and it gives me a point. I want to find the value that corresponds to 4 points to the left, and to the right of this value.

So lets say it tells me that the max of column 5 is 1.5 and it is located in row number 5 
How would I make the function move it 4 rows/points backwards?

Example:

```
max(data_10MIN(49000:51000,9)

ans = -3.5226
```

`data_10MIN(50251) = -3.5226`, so I would just know that 4 points backwards is `50247`, and moving 4 points forwards would be `50255` but how would I have a function do this for me? since `max(data_10MIN(49000:51000,9)` as a function does not give me the `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 0):

The [max](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function also returns the (first occurence) index of the maximum value. You can simply offset that value and get to your desired 4 points to the left/right.

```
[maxvalue, idx] = max(data);
left4idx = max(1, idx - 4);
right4idx = min(numel(data), idx+4);

left4_value = data(left4idx);
right4_value = data(right4idx);
```

(It is a  good idea to add a boundary check when adding/subtracting to an index, here I did that using the min/max functions.)

Comment: Okay, so I think that works. However I think my case is a little different. In my script, I have                                                                       eval(['VCathodicOh3(2,i) =' 'min(' 'data_' varnames{1} '(49000:51000,9));'])         where vcathodicoh3 is a new variable i'm making that acts on other data in my code. Basically I wanna edit this function in the script so that it takes 4 points to the left/right (depending on which one I want to use in that scenario) instead of just the min. How would i integrate your commands into my code?

Comment: using the index returns by `max` boils down to basic matlab, read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/235/introduction-to-matlab)

Comment: eval(['VCathodicOh3(2,i) =' 'min(' 'data_' varnames{1} '(49000:51000,9));'])

Comment: I have written a script that does the function:

    eval(['VCathodicOh3(2,i) =' 'min(' 'data_' varnames{1} '(49000:51000,9));']) 
In this, 'VCathodicOh3' is made by taking data from column 9 in different variables that are organized in arrays (they are 1:100000 rows by 10 columns).

I want to, instead of just finding the min, also add something to this function so that it takes the min, finds the point at which that min is at, and then move 4 points to the left of that point. @Gunther Struyf

Comment: again: [read the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/235/introduction-to-matlab), read examples, try stuff out; the question here is solved afaik; if you have further questions, the comments is not the place for that; search for answers yourself and [follow the guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)